# Is it possible to lock/force explorer's window width and height?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I am an admittedly particular power user and one thing that bothers me about Windows is that when certain games or programs are run they screw up my preferred window size for the file explorer. This usually happens with older games that utilize a 4:3 aspect ratio. I would like to know where the values for this are stored and if it is possible to make the values read-only so that in the event of a forced resize, I can simply restart explorer and have it revert to my preference. I am assuming this is stored in the registry under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` but I can't find anything that suggests the current window size for width and height *(this particular registry key is rather extensive)*. I have done some digging here and on other sites but I cannot find info on what specifically stores this setting.

It would be preferred that I do this natively in Windows, even though I do not know exactly where this setting is stored it is obvious that Windows keeps track of it somewhere. If it cannot be done natively I will just have to stick with it as is.

Comment: If you really need to do this, use xPlorer2 (zabkat). It always starts exactly the same way and usually in the same spot

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to an alternative solution, but I would prefer to use the built-in file explorer. I'm not sure I want to pay $30US for a third-party tool @John.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [Autohotkey scripting](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm). It is possible to write a script to organize windows as you see fit.
Natively, Windows doesn't have a window size manager except when you drag windows to the screen edges and it will resize them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I do not want to use third-party software. If it cannot be done natively then so be it, but there has to be something in Windows that stores this information. I will update my question to specify that I'd prefer a native OS method.

Comment: There is no way to lock Windows Explorer to a fixed position natively.  My suggestion above is a product I have been using for over a decade because it is so good.